# Python bottle send raw response to socket

Tags: python, websocket, bottle

I've been using gevent-websocket for a while, but then for some reason it mysteriously broke on both OSX and linux. People on bitbucket and pypi dismissed my request without responding to it, as did the people on stackoverflow. I'm planning on writing my own WebSocket implementation, but I need access to the raw connection object (like the socket object from the socket module) that manages the sending and receiving of raw data. Where can I find this in bottlepy? I'm looking for code that might look like this:

```
@route("/websocket")
def ws():
    raw_conn = ??? # socket object from socket module
    # initialize websocket here, following protocols and then send messages
    while True:
        raw_conn.send(raw_conn.recv()) # Simple echo
```

Comment: Would you mind linking to the SO question that you posted, regarding how `gevent-websocket` broke? I'm curious to see the details. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40876032/gevent-websocket-throws-protocolerror-when-socket-receive-is-called

Answer (score 0):

Some code I did for that that can be useful:

```
import abc
import socket


class Communication(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.port = port
        self.connexion = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def send_message(self, message):
        self.my_connexion.send(message.encode())

    def wait_for_message(self, nb_characters = 1024):
        message = self.my_connexion.recv(nb_characters)          
        return message.decode()

    def close_connexion(self):
        self.connexion.close()


class Client(Communication):
    def __init__(self, port):
        Communication.__init__(self, port)     
        self.connexion.connect(("localhost", port))
        self.my_connexion = self.connexion

class Server(Communication):
    def __init__(self, port, failed_connexion_attempt_max = 1):
        Communication.__init__(self, port)

        self.connexion.bind(("", port))
        self.connexion.listen(failed_connexion_attempt_max)
        self.my_connexion, address = self.connexion.accept()

    def close_connexion(self):
        self.client_connexion.close()
        self.connexion.close()
```

Comment: This can't help with bottlepy.